# Screen size support for tablets fails (calculation)

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm having a table with text and 4 quads.
Older Screenshot:
[image: table with text (2x size of the 4 quads]

The phone design works well, but if I try to make it for tablets it fails:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
width = size.x;
height = size.y;

int w=(int) ((width-(table.getPaddingLeft()+table.getPaddingRight())*2)/6);
//w->minimum widthsize of one quad view
```

I've a static listview menu in tablet mode with 225dip

I've tried to put it like: `+drawer` before `)/6);` it into the calculation and the same problem;
with this precalc.:

```
int drawer=0;//for phones
Resources r = getResources();
float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 225, r.getDisplayMetrics());

if(drawerLayout==null) {
    drawer=pixels;
}
```

What's wrong..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd a bracket mistake, so the drawer has to be summed and then removed from width

```
int w=(int) ((width-((table.getPaddingLeft()+table.getPaddingRight())*2+drawer))/6);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the default text size and let user make it resize use this code:
first implement the `OnTouchListener` to the Activity and use following code:

```
    public boolean onTouchEvent(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(null != scaleGestureDetector && v.getId() == R.id.TextView)
                scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }

public class simpleOnScaleGestureListener extends
    SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {

        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            float size = TextView.getTextSize();
            float factor = detector.getScaleFactor();
            float product = size*factor;
            TextView.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, product);
            size = TextView.getTextSize();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hope this will resolve your problem.

Comment: which textview? - I've added it with code -> 1 array for the texts andd for each row one

Comment: Than you have to apply this over the parent layout and write a generic method which will get all the textview from it's parent and set the size as mentioned above.

Comment: I'll try it, but I'd prefer a calculation mistake / hint